# Weka - Using multiple lines to define nominal values for class attribute

Tags: weka, arff

In my ARFF file instead of:

```
@ATTRIBUTE myclass {value1, value2, value3}
```

I would like to write something like:

```
@ATTRIBUTE myclass 
{
value1, 
value2, 
value3
}
```

Reason: myclass will eventually contain almost 1000 values and it would be easier to read and edit the arff file using the second format.

I've tried using the the above format but I get an error message saying "Unable to determine structure as arff.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible in Weka. You could keep a separate file where you list all your classes in your preferred format for editing/readability and convert it into Weka's format once you make any changes. For example if you use a [Unix-like](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-like) operation system the you could use the `tr` command in the terminal:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < <filename>
```

You can then copy the output into your ARFF file.